# Simple C# program using arrays throws an error

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

Well I'm trying to write a program in which if you add for example 3 integers in the array, let's say 3 2 1, it will add them again after it so it becomes 321 321.

Here is the code I need to fix. And sorry for the stupid question I am a beginner with arrays.

I get this error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

My code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int arraylength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[arraylength];

        for (int i = 0; i < arraylength + 1 / 2; i++)
        {
            int typed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            array[i] = typed;

            if (i == arraylength / 2)
            {
                for (int a = arraylength + 1 / 2; a < arraylength + 1; a++)
                {
                    array[a] = typed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: Change it to `a < arrayLenght` instead of `a < arrayLenght+1` since the arrayIndex is from 0 to arrayLenght so trying to do array[a] where a = arrayLenght will fail

Comment: (arraylenght + 1) / 2

Comment: @Code-Apprentice error on line 14 (array[a] = typed)

Comment: This: `arraylenght + 1 / 2` will equal `arraylenght` because it means `arraylenght + (1 / 2)` and `1/2` equals 0. I am pretty sure that is not what you meant.

Comment: @raghav710 it is not array.Lenght it is a int arraylenght so i need it to be incrased by +1 so if i type the lenght to be 5 it will be proper so it is 6 since arrays start from 0

Comment: @raghav710 "works fine" is relative. The code most likely does not accomplish the task that the OP wants. If it does, it works a lot harder than necessary.

Comment: @NikolayAtanasov "if i type the lenght to be 5 it will be proper so it is 6 since arrays start from 0" That is incorrect. If the user enters a length of `5` the valid indices go from `0` to `4`. This means all indices are strictly less than 5: `i < arraylenght`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices in C# start at `0` and end at `length - 1`. You need to remove the `+ 1` from each of your for loop conditions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylenght / 2; i++)
```

and

```
for (int a = (arraylenght + 1) / 2; a < arraylenght; a++)
```

I also suggest that you change `arraylenght` to `arraylength`. Since you probably autocompleted this every time you used it, the misspelling occurs consistently throughout your code and the compiler is satisfied. However, misspellings make it difficult for humans to read your code.

p.s. Your code doesn't do what you think it does. I suggest you step away from the computer for a moment and write **in words** what you are trying to accomplish. Describe each step of your solution in as much detail as you can. Then look at how your words match with the code you wrote. You will probably find that you do not need nested loops.